# Sendgrid not finding any templates when using urlPath: "templates"

Tags: c#, sendgrid

I am using Sendgrid and am trying to access my templates.
Normally code underneath should provide the response var with my templates

```
var client = GetSendGridClient();

var response = await client.RequestAsync(SendGrid.SendGridClient.Method.GET, urlPath: "templates");
```

However it seems sendgrid is not returning any templates.
I thought "templates" was the default urlpath for my templates
And yes I have active templates on my SendGrid account, and yes My Sendgrid Client is being succesfully created.

Answer (score 0):

In the [SendGrid C# Library documentation](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/dc1833dd8b8c6370627e6ed1607ecd286beb3a15/USAGE.md#initialization), they show:

```
string apiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("NAME_OF_THE_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_FOR_YOUR_SENDGRID_KEY");
var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
```

You have: `var client = GetSendGridClient();`. Since you're not providing the `apiKey`, you're probably not authenticating, so it's not returning any data. Have you made sure that the `client` instance you generate is authenticated or otherwise "logged in"?

Comment: Thx For the response, this was not the problem in the end it seems that my code only works with Legacy Templates and not the standard transactional. After creating a Legacy template SendGrid managed to find the templates.

Answer (score 0):

in the end it seems that my code only works with Legacy Templates and not the standard transactional. After creating a Legacy template SendGrid managed to find the templates.

Answer (score 0):

To create a transaction template (none legacy type) add "generation": "dynamic" to the JSON when POSTing.  For example.

```
{
  "name": "my_template",
  "generation": "dynamic"
}
```

**NB: This appears to be an undocumented feature.!!**